# How to properly set precision for doubles in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm working on a project where I need to do some math and give the user output with dollars in it, so I would like to have my console tell the user an answer like `$20.15` instead of `$20.153`. I used the set precision function as such:
`cout << setprecision(2);`, but rather than have the numbers become what I want them to be, they are converted into scientific notation.

I'm outputting a lot of numbers, so having a function like `setprecision` would be best for me for ease of use.

How do I properly have the numbers displayed with only two decimal places and not have the console give me numbers in scientific notation?

Thanks

Nathan

EDIT:

Here is the part of my code I'm having problems with:

```
int main() {

cout << setprecision(2);

if (totalCostHybrid < totalCostNonHybrid) {
            cout << "Hybrid car: " << endl;
            cout << "Total cost: " << totalCostHybrid << endl;
            cout << "Total gallons used: " << milesPerYear / hybridEffic << endl;
            cout << "Total gas cost: " << gasCostHybrid << endl;
            cout << "Non-hybrid car: " << endl;
            cout << "Total cost: " << totalCostNonHybrid << endl;
            cout << "Total gallons used: " << milesPerYear / nonHybridEffic << endl;
            cout << "Total gas cost: " << gasCostNonHybrid << endl;
            cout << "Hybrid is cheaper!" << endl;
}
```

Obviously there's more to it, but this is what I need help with.

Comment: don't use doubles to represent real money

Comment: Could you post the code you're using?

Comment: What is the best way to represent money?

Comment: represent money as single long value, which represents cents (minimal coin), or use something like BigDecimal (there are a lot of different libraries for c++)

Comment: @Samer - no, it's just the opposite: the question is about limiting the precision of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix that, you should use fixed floating-point notation for cout. You can find more info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/).

Try addind `cout << fixed` to your code, like the code below. To set the precision to `2`, you can use the `precision` property.

```
cout << fixed;
cout.precision(2);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << fixed;
    cout.precision(2);

    if (totalCostHybrid < totalCostNonHybrid) {
            cout << "Hybrid car: " << endl;
            cout << "Total cost: " << totalCostHybrid << endl;
            cout << "Total gallons used: " << milesPerYear / hybridEffic << endl;
            cout << "Total gas cost: " << gasCostHybrid << endl;
            cout << "Non-hybrid car: " << endl;
            cout << "Total cost: " << totalCostNonHybrid << endl;
            cout << "Total gallons used: " << milesPerYear / nonHybridEffic << endl;
            cout << "Total gas cost: " << gasCostNonHybrid << endl;
            cout << "Hybrid is cheaper!" << endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: Going through some more test cases with the code, when I get answers like 1.66666667 or 3.3333333, it does not seem to work when I receive an answer which is 1/3 or 2/3

Comment: What are you getting as an output? For 1/3 and 2/3 with that exact code I get 0.33 and 0.67 here.

Comment: Are you sure you're not making an integer division there? 1/3 should output 0.00, but 1.0/3 should output 0.33

Comment: All of my variables, with the exception of strings, are doubles. So I'm dividing and multiplying by doubles as well.

Comment: But are you explicitly writing 1/3? Because even if you write `double d = 1/3`, d will be equal to 0. What output are you getting?

Comment: I am not explicitly writing 1/3. Both the 1 value and the 3 value are input by the user. For example, the `milesPerYear` is at 100 and the `hybridEffic` is at 60. This should print out 1.67, but instead will print 1.6666667

Comment: Then its a likely a problem with another part of your code, which you didn't post. Try for yourself writing a program with only this in the main: `cout << fixed;` `cout.precision(2);` `double d = 1.0/3;` `cout << d;`, and see for yourself that it works =)

Comment: If you want, I can continue helping you  [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101814/discussion-between-gabriel-ilharco-and-nathan-lundgren).

Comment: The reason I wouldn't see this fix work was because of fatal error C1075 (I forgot a } at the end of the code). Stupid coder :P

Answer (score 1):

Iostreams are a pain for formatting floating-point values. But why are you using floating-point to represent currency values? You should store integer pennies (or tenth-pennies) because, though you're not measuring in whole numbers of dollars, your values are actually fixed-point. And you really don't need the trouble that floating-point brings. And then you can stream the whole and "fractional" parts of your value separately (use `/` and `%`!), as integers, with a `'.'` in the middle.

In the meantime, try [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

Comment: As good as it sounds, it is not always possible to express money in integers. You actually need to count in fractions.

Comment: @SergeyA: You still have an absolute level of accuracy required = fixed-point. Using floating-point for money is bonkers, unless you're dealing in amounts of hugely varying orders of magnitude and aren't actually accounting. Otherwise, can you give me an example of when you can't express money in integers?

Comment: @LRiO, when I said 'fractions' I meant (I don't know proper english term for that) a *natural fraction*, for example, 1/3 * 2/3 is ((1 + 2) / 3). Don't know how to explain, I lack math english words. In financial software, you often need to divide and end is non-whole nubmbers, which than need to be added or multiplied.

Comment: @SergeyA: Financial software does not use floating-point to represent currency values.

Comment: Unfortunately, it often does. Do you know why you are usually allowed to have a mismatch of up to 30 dollars between two trading accounts with instituion eating the difference? :) But it should not.

Comment: @SergeyA: That's called "skimming" and it's about as illegal as it gets.

Comment: Nope, this is not skimming, and this is one hundered percent legal and blessed by ADP when a 'wash' account is used.

Answer (score 0):

Cheat and watch purists go crazy...

```
    double time;  //Only want two decimal places.
    double timeCon = time * 100.0;  //Pull out the two decimals I want.
    int timeCut = timeCon;  //Cut all decimal values.
    double timeRevert = timeCut / 100.0;  //Laugh.
    cout << timeRevert << endl;  //Watch heads explode.
```

Comment: it would be better to use libraries that do this.