# Losing data when casting float to int in c++

Tags: c++

Aside from the obvious expected loss of fractional values, I don't see why this should happen...

Consider the following snippet from a homework assignment used to convert numerical digits to english phrases:

```
int main() {
    float dollars;

    cout << "Please supply a dollar amount between $0.01 and $9999.99 (without the dollar sign): ";
    while (true) {
        cin >> dollars;

        if (cin.fail() || dollars < 0.01 || dollars > 9999.99) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "You provided an invalid number. Please try again: ";
        } else {
            // Test code:
            cout << "You entered: " << dollars << endl;
            cout << "Times 100 without cast: " << dollars * 100 << endl;
            cout << "Times 100 with cast: " << (int)(dollars * 100) << endl;
            cout << "Cents: " << ((int)(dollars * 100)) % 100 << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    printDollarsAsString(dollars);

    return 0;
}
```

I've noticed that when supplying the value `9999.21`, the outputs of the second and third `cout` statements in the `else` block differ by 1. For example, here is the output when I run this code:

```
Please supply a dollar amount between $0.01 and $9999.99 (without the dollar sign): 9999.21
You entered: 9999.21
Times 100 without cast: 999921
Times 100 with cast: 999920
Cents: 20
```

How can I fix this so that the cents value is retrieved correctly? Is there a different approach I can take?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286394/for-loop-in-c-using-double-breaking-out-one-step-early-boundary-value-not-rea

Comment: Do any of these answers help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544394/c-floating-point-to-integer-type-conversions

Comment: I would suggest to use an integer type instead of a floating point type.  You could store the number of **cents** in the variable instead of the number of **dollars**.  Just be careful when reading values out.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35045719/4342498) about storing currency as a floating point number.

Comment: also lines like `dollars < 0.01` can cause you problem, when comparing up close value differing by precision, since dollars is float while `0.01` is double -> https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/doubles-are-not-floats-so-dont-compare-them/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
    cout << "Times 100 without cast: " << dollars * 100 << endl;
    cout << "Times 100 with cast: " << (int)(dollars * 100 + 0.5) << endl;
```

It is because of rounding.

full code:

```
   } else {
        // Test code:
        cout << "You entered: " << dollars << endl;
        cout << "Times 100 without cast: " << dollars * 100 << endl;
        cout << "Times 100 with cast: " << (int)(dollars * 100 + 0.5) << endl;
        cout << "Cents: " << ((int)(dollars * 100 + 0.5)) % 100 << endl;
        break;
   }
```

alternatively:

```
   } else {
        // Test code:
        cout << "You entered: " << dollars << endl;
        cout << "Times 100 without cast: " << dollars * 100 << endl;
        cout << "Times 100 with cast: " << (int)round(dollars * 100) << endl;
        cout << "Cents: " << ((int)round(dollars * 100)) % 100 << endl;
        break;
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
        cout << "Times 100 without cast: " << dollars * 100 << endl;
        cout << "Times 100 with cast: " << (int)(dollars * 100) << endl;
```

When you cast to int you are truncating the number, not rounding. In this case, the `.21` cannot be storted exactly by binary floating point, because it actually comes out to a repeating number. The repeating number is slightly less than `.21`. So when you multiply by 100 you get `999920.9...` which truncates to `999920` with the cast.

Comment: VS2013express:      `dollars = dollars * 100;` dollars=999921.000

Comment: @StahlRat similarly when I do it using g++ from MinGW, I get 999921 as the output (as seen above)

Answer (score 1):

Just because You've asked about different approach :)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

...

      std::string str_dollars;
      char delim = '.';
      std::vector<std::string> elems;

      std::cin >> str_dollars;
      std::stringstream ss(str_dollars);
      std::string item;
      while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
         elems.push_back(item);
      }
      cout << "Cents: " << elems[1] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it with the help of [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525).

This also allows me to accept fractional cents, and I can round it accordingly. The following outputs what I expect:

```
            cout << "Times 100 without cast: " << round(dollars * 100) << endl;
            cout << "Times 100 with cast: " << (int) round(dollars * 100) << endl;
            cout << "Cents: " << (int) round(dollars * 100) % 100 << endl;
```